# How can I remove DisplayPort from audio devices?

Tags: macos, display, audio

When I connect my external monitor it shows up in the audio settings.
[image]

That makes zero sense, as this monitor does not have any speakers. 
How can I prevent it from popping up as an audio output option?

Comment: It makes perfect sense. The U2713HM has an audio output which it is reporting to the computer, therefore it shows up as an output device.

Comment: Though, interestingly, I have a U2713HM & a U2713H both connected via DisplayPort & neither show up in Sound.